# Crystal Reports does not print correctly in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, crystal-reports

I am using the `CrystalReportViewer` in a ASP.net application using VS 2010. The reports were built using CR version 2011.

When printing in firefox a bunch garbage is printed out.

The print works fine in IE and Chrome. Any idea how to make firefox print correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and the only idea I can come up with thus far is to trap the printing on server-side, then use crystal reports object to do the printing. I know its a hack, but it seems to be the only way right now.